# DateTime.ParseExact for non-conventional years

Tags: c#, date

I'm trying to read dates in the following format using a single format string:

```
"1000.12.31"
"999.12.31"
"99.12.31"
```

These would correspond to dates in the years 1000 AD, 999 AD and 99 AD.

I've tried the following format strings:

`yyyy.M.d`. This fails for the years 999 and 99.

`yy.M.d`. This fails for 1000 and 999. It also interprets 99 as 1999.

I'm about to resort to parsing it manually (it's simple enough for that), but i'm curious if something like this is even possible with `DateTime.ParseExact`, or perhaps with another built-in method?

Comment: "99.12.31" is ambiguous to a human as well.  *Nobody* will go "ah, that's of course the year 99 in the reign of Marcus Ulpius Nerva Traianus Augustus".  Every picks 1999.  It doesn't get better with a machine.

Comment: @leppie: nope, same result as `yy.M.d` iirc. @Hans To me, in this context it is not ambiguous though. I know that i always want 99 to be 99, and not 1999, i just can't specify that. Like days and months, they could be ambiguous (1/2, is that feb 1st or jan 2nd?), but if you know what to expect, you are able to specify that in a format string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is trivial to parse manually; I don’t think it’s worth the effort trying to adapt it to work with `DateTime.ParseExact`.

```
string str = "99.12.31";
int[] parts = str.Split('.').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
DateTime date = new DateTime(parts[0], parts[1], parts[2]);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way would be to take the existing string, stick a few zeros in front of the year, and use your existing DateTime.ParseExact.

However you implement it, I'd go with doing a little manual string massaging, and doing the heavy lifting with DateTime.ParseExact.

```
static DateTime ParseExactYear(string input)
{
    switch (input.IndexOf('.'))
    {
        case 1: input = "000" + input; break;
        case 2: input = "00" + input; break;
        case 3: input = "0" + input; break;
    }

    return DateTime.ParseExact(input, "yyyy.M.d", null);
}

Debug.WriteLine(ParseExactYear("1000.12.31"));
Debug.WriteLine(ParseExactYear("999.12.31"));
Debug.WriteLine(ParseExactYear("99.12.31"));
Debug.WriteLine(ParseExactYear("9.12.31"));

Debug.WriteLine(ParseExactYear("1000.1.1"));
Debug.WriteLine(ParseExactYear("999.1.1"));
Debug.WriteLine(ParseExactYear("99.1.1"));
Debug.WriteLine(ParseExactYear("9.1.1"));

Output:
12/31/1000 12:00:00 AM
12/31/0999 12:00:00 AM
12/31/0099 12:00:00 AM
12/31/0009 12:00:00 AM
1/1/1000 12:00:00 AM
1/1/0999 12:00:00 AM
1/1/0099 12:00:00 AM
1/1/0009 12:00:00 AM
```

Comment: And then it blows up on `"1.1.1"` :*(

Comment: This is assuming that months and days are always represented in 2 digits.

Comment: @Matthew: And ignoring single digit years too ;p

Comment: Sorry, months and days are not always 2 digits, that's what the `M.d`-part says ;)

Comment: Quite right, I forgot about single-digit months & days. See edit.

Answer (score 2):

It interprets 99 as 1999 because of the current culture's `DateTimeFormatInfo` values. If you want to change the parsing behavior you must change the `DateTimeFormatInfo`:

```
string eg = "9.1.2";
DateTime dt;

var fi = new System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo();
fi.Calendar = (System.Globalization.Calendar)fi.Calendar.Clone();
fi.Calendar.TwoDigitYearMax = 99;
fi.ShortDatePattern = "y.M.d";
bool b = DateTime.TryParse(eg, fi, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);
```

New instances of `DateTimeFormatInfo` share the same `Calendar` object; you have to `Clone` it if you want to customize specific instances.