# C# DateTime.ParseExact determining year prefix

Tags: c#, date, datetime

I have a requirement regarding the parsing of date strings of the form "dd/MM/yy" such that if the year is deemed greater than 30 years from the current year then it would prefix the year with 19. In the other instance it is prefixed with 20.

Examples:

01/01/50 -> 01/01/1950 
01/01/41 -> 01/01/2041

I'm not sure how DateTime.ParseExact decides what prefix it should use or how I can force it one way or the other (it does appear to make a sane assumption as 01/01/12 -> 01/01/2012, I just don't know how to dictate the point at which it will switch).

Comment: i don't think it is possible by `ParseExact`.

Comment: Is it possible with any part of the c# date api or am I looking at writing my own conditional block to perform the conversion before parsing?

Comment: Please see [Parsing Non-Conventional Years](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11249715/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [`Calendar.TwoDigitYearMax`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendar.twodigityearmax%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property.

> Gets or sets the last year of a 100-year range that can be represented
>   by a 2-digit year.

In your case, something like this would work:

```
// Setup 
var cultureInfo = (CultureInfo)Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
var calendar = cultureInfo.Calendar;
calendar.TwoDigitYearMax = DateTime.Now.Year + 30;
cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.Calendar = calendar;

// Parse
var _1950 = DateTime.ParseExact("01/01/50", "dd/MM/yy", cultureInfo);
var _2041 = DateTime.ParseExact("01/01/41", "dd/MM/yy", cultureInfo);
```

Comment: Does this work with `ParseExact` or are you suggesting to convert it to a four digit year with `Calendar.ToFourDigitYear()` and then use `ParseExact`? +1 for knowing this even existed

Comment: This works with `ParseExact` as it takes a `CultureInfo` as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that `ParseExact` can do your job, so here my version with `conditional blocks` but works.

Try This:

```
            DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now;
            String strDate = "01/01/41";
            DateTime userDate=DateTime.ParseExact(strDate, "dd/MM/yy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            currentDate=currentDate.AddYears(30);
            if ((userDate.Year%100) > (currentDate.Year%100))
            {
                strDate = strDate.Insert(6, "19");
            }
            else
            {
                strDate = strDate.Insert(6, "20");
            }
            DateTime newUserDate = DateTime.ParseExact(strDate, "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```